# Libraries for (label propagation algorithms/frequent subgraph mining) for graphs in R

Tags: classification, r, graphs

**General description of the problem**

I have a graph where some vertices are labeled with a type with 3 or 4 possible values. For the other vertices, the type is unknown.
My goal is to use the graph to predict the type for vertices that are unlabeled.

**Possible framework**

I suspect this fits into the general framework of label propagation problems, based on my reading of the literature (e.g., see [this paper](http://lvk.cs.msu.su/~bruzz/articles/classification/zhu02learning.pdf) and [this paper](http://www.csc.ncsu.edu/faculty/samatova/practical-graph-mining-with-R/slides/pdf/Frequent_Subgraph_Mining.pdf))

Another method that is mentioned often is `Frequent Subgraph Mining`, which includes algorithms like `SUBDUE`,`SLEUTH`, and `gSpan`.

**Found in R**

The only label propagation implementation I managed to find in `R` is `label.propagation.community()` from the `igraph` library. 
However, as the name suggests, it is mostly used to find communities, not for classifying unlabeled vertices.

There also seems to be several references to a `subgraphMining` library (here for example), but it looks like it is missing from CRAN.

**Question**

Do you know of a library or framework for the task described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old post, but there is a subgraph package and accompanying book/documentation for doing this in R:
https://www.csc.ncsu.edu/faculty/samatova/practical-graph-mining-with-R/PracticalGraphMiningWithR.html

Although I personally don't get the connection between subgraph mining and label propagation in this case. SVD++ might be closer to what you're looking for (supported by GraphX of Spark, which I think also supports label propagation).
http://spark.apache.org/graphx/